# Pass variables to DATABASE preventing mysql injection node and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

So, I started to develop in nodejs and mysql. I read in some forums that the correct way to do the insertion in mysql would be using variables to prevent mysql injection, however I tried in several ways to insert them and I couldn't. I was only able to do them manually as follows:

```
 db.query('UPDATE spreadsheetUsers SET weight="1" WHERE weekDay="1" AND idStudent="1" ', (error,results) =>
```

How could I do to insert them using variables?

The way I was trying was like this:

```
 db.query('UPDATE spreadsheetUsers SET weight=? WHERE weekDay=? AND idStudent=? '
,{weight:value[0], weekDay:daySelected, idStudent:idStudent }, (error,results) =>
```

I guess im missing something, could someone help?

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: Sorry the error was sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your server version for the right syntax". However, tushar already reported what was wrong with my code, i was using {} instead of []. I appreciate the support guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values

```
{weight:value[0], weekDay:daySelected, idStudent:idStudent }, (error,results) =>
```

the parameterized query should be **array** not **object**

```
 db.query('UPDATE spreadsheetUsers SET weight=? WHERE weekDay=? AND idStudent=?'
,[value[0], daySelected, idStudent], (error,results) =>
```

You can use this style also

```
db.query({
  sql: 'UPDATE spreadsheetUsers SET weight=? WHERE weekDay=? AND idStudent=?',
  values: [value[0], daySelected, idStudent']
}, function (error, results, fields) {
  // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
  // results will contain the results of the query
  // fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any)
});
```